# Rails form to update a record within an index partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to allow the user update certain fields from within the index. However, when I press the button on the screen to update, nothing happens and the record in the database remains unchanged. What am I missing or doing wrong?

> **views/company_pays/_index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Company Pays</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Apply deduction1</th>
      <th>Apply deduction2</th>
      <th>Apply deduction3</th>
      <th>Apply deduction4</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @company_pays.each do |company_pay| %>
      <tr>        
        <td><%= company_pay.description %></td>
        <td><%= company_pay.pay_sub_head.short_desc %></td>

      <td class="input"><%= form_for company_pay, :method => :patch do |f| %></td>
        <% if company_pay.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(company_pay.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company_pay from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% company_pay.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>  
        <td class="input"><%= f.text_field :units %></td>
        <td class="input"><%= f.check_box :apply_deduction1 %></td>
        <td class="input"><%= f.check_box :apply_deduction2 %></td>
        <td class="input"><%= f.check_box :apply_deduction3 %></td>
        <td class="input"><%= f.check_box :apply_deduction4 %></td>
        <td class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update" %>
      <% end %>
        </td>


      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: When you click submit, does anything happen on the server? If not, what does the resulting html look like? I'm suspecting there's some weirdness around the form and td tags. Otherwise, can you paste the server call and params?

Comment: When I inspect the resulting html I can't see any html for this section. I'm guessing it's because the page that contains this was served using AJAX? So when I inspect the source html I can only see the containing div pre the Ajax call. Is this right? I'd have expected to see the html, post the AJAX call?